# problemas al subir csv separado por comas

Tags: c#, asp.net

buen día Estoy intentando subir un archivo en formato csv separado por comas con asp.net y c#, todo funciona bien pero tengo un detalle que es el siguiente:

Supongamos que tengo un excel con 4 columnas

Nombre, Edad, Dirección, Cantidad

si una de las columnas/celdas del excel tiene comas, por ejemplo la columna cantidad tuviera algo así: 1,000.00

o la columna dirección: calle tal, Ciudad tal, Numero tal

enter image description here

a la hora de convertirlo a formato csv separado por comas y al quererlo subir con c#, hago algo como esto: string[] row = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');

para saber o contar cuantas columnas tiene cada filas, originalmente eran cuatro columnas que se separaron con coma pero en la columna dirección y cantidad también tenia una coma entonces al hacer el split(',') me contaría dos columnas mas serian 6, les agradecería mucho si pudieran ayudarme a solucionar ese detalle, ya que se tendrían que guardar a la Base de Datos 4 columnas y no 6

Comment: El formato CSV tiene manera de escapar las comas mediante el uso de por ejemplo comillas dobles como si fuera un string de C#. Las reglas no son tan sencillas así que olvidate de parsearlo por tu cuenta y utiliza una librería. Te recomiendo [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: No es posible utilizar un separador diferente a la coma, por ejemplo, un pipe "|", si el archivo está en formato Excel puede subirlo directamente de ese formato.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el usuario es el que va a subir el archivo y no sabemos que tipo de formato va a subir podría ser un excel o csv

Answer (score 0):

Intente usar expresiones regulares. puede usar este patron:

",(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)"

ejemplo de como implementar:

```
string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(file);

for (int i = 0; i < lineas.Count(); i++)
{
    linea = Regex.Split(lineas[i], ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
}
```